# Transfer Items, Tamed Pets, Etc between users

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console

I was playing a world with my friend split-screen, and I was using his "User 1" account. We made a really good world and we want to continue playing it. So there is a way to transfer items, but is there a way for us to transfer my pets to my other account?

Comment: Do you want to transfer it to another account on the same PS4 or to another account on a different PS4? (May be important for the answer).

Comment: Yes and no. The account I want to transfer in is my PSN account which ks signed in on both PS4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Online or Split Screen, it is not possible to transfer items to the second user. The Host (main player) will be able to keep the changes made the world and any items collected, but any items collected my the second player will be lost.

Therefore, it's important to put all the seconds player's items into a chest before ending play, so you can pick them up when you play the next time. Otherwise, anything the second player is holding / carrying is lost.